# Cambiar de tamaño imagen al bajar el scroll en HTML

Tags: html5

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi imagen cambie de tamaño al bajar el scroll? Este es el código.

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilos.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <scrip src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
        <input type="text" name="q" size="15" maxlength="255" value="buscar" />
        </form>

         <center>
         <img src="logoModoRock-03.png" width="80" height="80">
         </center>

    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Código CSS:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
    background: #fffffa;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #252932;
}
header{
     position: fixed;
     height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Rigoberto, necesitas mostrar algo de iniciativa al momento de publicar una pregunta, qué has intentado ? que problemas te has encontrado ? Pequeño tip, deberías investigar el evento scroll para javascript(quizá con [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/))

Comment: @Rigoberto Lo que estás intentando es que la imagen crezca cuando bajas el scroll y que tome su posición original cuando llega al tope?

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr esto necesitas añadir algo de código javascript en el evento scroll y con esta información asignar una clase en particular que modifique las propiedades del objeto.

Ejemplo:

CSS

```
.newClass {
  height: 60px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$document.scroll(function() {
  $(".title").toggleClass(newClass, $document.scrollTop() >= 50);
});
```